# Why is depth-limited is preferable to minimax without depth limited

Tags: search, minimax

I have read about a question that says the following:

Why is depth-limited minimax preferable to minimax?

One of the wrong answers was:

> The depth-limited minimax will achieve the same output as minimax without depth-limited, but can sometimes use less memory.

Why is the above answer is wrong? I mean, don't both of these algorithms always achieve the same output, and because the depth-limited minimax doesn't always explore all the states this makes it use less memory?

Comment: Can you please provide a reference that describes this "depth-limited minimax"? I think you're not talking about alpha-beta pruning, but some other variation. Wikipedia provides the pseudocode for the depth-limited minimax [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), but if you have a more reliable reference that you're using that describes it, feel free to share it with us. It might also be a good idea to provide the link to the original source of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'non-depth-limited minimax' is minimax with iterative deepening, it does not have to result in the same output as depth-limited minimax. It can traverse the tree deeper and thus find different optimal answers for a 'deeper' layer.